# How do I return literal values of a PHP string so it runs as code?

Tags: php, arrays, string, eval, array-filter

I am not sure I am using the right terms even here, but I will try and explain. I am using PHP's [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function to filter products and it calls back to a custom function I made where I add the filter(s). I can do this hard-coded very easy, but I obviously want it to be dynamic:

To cut a long story short, the custom filter function returns to the array_filter() function like so:

```
return ($arr['colour']=='Red' || $arr['colour']=='White');
```

This works fine if hardcoded like the above, and filters the array as expected to only show products that are red or white. However, I need this to be dynamic.

So how can I construct a string of values and then use this in the return statement?

For example:

```
$var = "$arr['colour'] == 'Red' || $arr['colour'] == 'White'";
return ($var);
```

It does not work. I have tried using eval() (I don't want to use this anyway!), and it didn't work still.

I have a loop as follows constructing the string from an array:

```
// $value=array of filters e.g colour=Black, colour=Red

$filterparts = explode("=", $value);

$filters[] = '$arr[\'' . $filterparts[0] . '\'] == \'' . $filterparts[1] . '\'';
// Creates array e.g $arr['colour'] = 'Red'

$imploded_filter = implode(" || ", $uniquefilters);
// Creates string, e.g. $arr['colour'] = 'Red' || $arr['colour'] = 'White'
```

So if I echo $imploded_filter I get the extract string I would like to return:

```
echo $imploded_filter;
// Outputs $arr['colour'] = 'Red' || $arr['colour'] = 'White'
```

However if I do

```
return($imploded_filter);
```

it obviously isn't evaluating the string as hard code, so what can I do? Do I need to do something to the string or return it a different way, or construct the code I need to return in a totally different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array keys can be specified dynamically. There isn't any need for `eval()`:

```
$value = $array[$key];
```

You can build a list of filters and match each of them in the `array_filter()` callback:

```
$filters = array(
    array('colour', array('white', 'blue')), // Multiple accepted values (OR)
    array('material', 'Fine Bone China'), // Single accepted value
);

$filtered = array_filter($products, function ($item) use ($filters) {
    // Match all filters
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        // Detect multi-value filter
        $isArrayFilter = is_array($filter[1]);

        if (
            // Check if multi-value filter doesn't match
            $isArrayFilter && !in_array($item[$filter[0]], $filter[1])
            // Check if a single-value filter doesn't match
            || !$isArrayFilter && $item[$filter[0]] != $filter[1]
        ) {
            // Filter doesn't match - exclude the item
            return false;
        }
    }

    // All filters match - include the item
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the job well, is it out of the scope of this question (or even the array_filter function!) to ask if its possible to work it so its OR for all values within a category (e.g colour) and then AND to combine it with other categories?

Comment: For example colour="red" || colour="blue" AND material="metal" || material="paper"   ... at the moment it's just checking if ANY of them exist which is fine but be nice to add this functionality to it.

Comment: You can support array values in `$filterparts[1]` (`$filter[1]`). If it's an array, you match it with `in_array($arr[$filter[0]], $filter[1])` instead of just comparing it.

Comment: Hi I'm really sorry but could you dumb that down for me please or give me an example, my brain is frazzled today lol. say I had an array colour="red", colour="blue", material="wood" how can all the colours be matched as OR and then say AND material= wood, so it'd need to filter "all red OR blue products that ARE made of wood"

Comment: **1)** parse filters so each filter has this structure: `['property', 'value']` or `['property', ['value1', 'value2']]` (if multiple values are provided) **2)** support array filter values in the `array_filter()` callback like this: `if (is_array($filter[1]) && in_array($arr[$filter[0]], $filter[1]) || !is_array($filter[1]) && $arr[$filter[0]] == $filter[1]) {`

Comment: hi @ShiraNai7 it's not having the expected result for some reason, I have set the filters as follows: $filters=array(array('colour',array("white","blue")),array('material','Fine Bone China'));   and the callback as you put in comment above:

Comment: $filtered = array_filter($products, function ($arr) use ($filters) {
    // try to match all filters
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        if (is_array($filter[1]) && in_array($arr[$filter[0]], $filter[1]) || !is_array($filter[1]) && $arr[$filter[0]] == $filter[1]) {
            // filter has matched
            return true;
        }
    }
    // no filter has matched
    return false;
});

Comment: it is returning 6 results (there are 6 bone china products) whatever I select in the colour part, whereas it should only show 2 products (1 white bone china product, 1 blue bone china product) if it was working how I'd want it to? Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer with new code. (You weren't using the filter callback I was expecting.)

Comment: thanks @ShiraNai7 but if I replace the code with the above the page just white screens, I can't find a useful error but further down the page it has the warning below, swapping the code back for the older code and the page displays and this error goes, any ideas?? 
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: PS I removed the , from the second array in the filters array, that didn't help though (but I don't think the comma should be there on the end of second array anyway?

Comment: if I swap the true and false around in the returns the page does at least load, it's as if if it matches its just returning "true" rather than the filtered array or something??

Comment: Check your PHP version. The code I've posted should work in PHP 5.3 or newer. I've passed some test data to the filter and it works fine. Throw away code from previous comments.

Comment: Hi I'm on PHP 5.4, I've just realised it was as simple as the lower case colour names in the filter list... wow I am having one of those days, thanks SO much for all your help with this if I could upvote more than once I would!

Answer (score 0):

```
$colors = ['Red', 'White'];
$products = array_filter($products, function ($product) use ($colors) {
    return in_array($product['color'], $colors);
});
```

There's virtually never any reason or need to "dynamically create PHP source code". There's always an operation that can do what you want on any number of elements without needing to concatenate `||` operators. Here `in_array` is a perfectly fine function to test one value against many. You can pass in the colors array dynamically using `use ($colors)`.

The sanest workaround for ancient PHP versions is to approximate the anonymous callback with a class:

```
class InArrayFilterCallback {

    public $data = array();
    public $key;

    public __construct($data, $key) {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public callback($item) {
        return in_array($item[$this->key], $this->data);
    }

}

$products = array_filter($products, array(new InArrayFilterCallback($colors, 'color'), 'callback'));
```

Of course, you could also just use a simple `foreach` loop instead...

Comment: Hi and thanks @deceze , do you know if this works on PHP < 5.5? I am  getting a lot of errors trying to use that code :(

Comment: This works since 5.3, since anonymous functions were introduced. For even older versions (which are positively ancient now!!) there are any number of possible workarounds. What version do you need to support?

Comment: Hi I'm on 5.4 but can't get either of these to work :/ the workaround just white screens and doesn't even give an error for some reason(!)

Comment: OK I am so dumb, I hadn't seen the american "color" spelling when in my array it's "colour"... all working now I think, just need to work a few bits out still!

Comment: So going back to the original issue of making this dynamic, how would I transform your solution to allow it to be passed a colour, material etc etc , at the moment you've got things like $product['color'], $colors hard-coded whereas I have an array of values like "material=metal", "colour"="Black" etc etc I need to pass to the filter dynamically?

Comment: How dynamic does this have to be? Since this is a tiny one-liner to write, it may make a lot more sense to have a bunch of those `array_filter` calls in a row, each filtering for something else. Also, you're already passing `$colors` in dynamically, you could be passing in the key to check for dynamically too, and then use a loop. Last but not least, the others answers here show you how to have a bunch of filter conditions and test for them within one filter callback.

Comment: Thanks I really do appreciate it, I have upvoted but accepted the answer below as that did it dynamically as well, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `in_array` function, like so:

```
$filters = [
    'colour' => [
        'red',
        'blue',
    ]
];
array_filter($list, function ($item) use ($filters) {
    foreach ($filters as $index => $filter) {
        if (!in_array($item[$index], $filter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
});
```

It is never a good idea to make a string and eval'uate it.